# Is there any way to install MongoDB on Windows like Ubuntu..?

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, mongodb, mongoose

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 2930ADAE8CAF5059EE73BB4B58712A2291FA4AD5

echo "deb [ arch=amd64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu trusty/mongodb-org/3.6 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.6.list

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org

mkdir data

echo "mongod --dbpath=data --nojournal" > mongod

chmod a+x mongod
```

Is there any similar way to install MongoDB on Windows, like using these commands on Ubuntu? If there is.. What are the requirements?

Comment: Here's what I found on google: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows-unattended/

Answer (score 0):

`apt-get` is a linux package manager. There are some Windows package managers, too:

- [winget](https://winget.run/): Official Microsoft Windows package manager
- [appget](https://appget.net/): The project [Microsoft copied](https://www.zdnet.com/article/microsoft-credits-maker-of-package-manager-it-copied-for-windows-10-but-offers-no-apology/)
- [scoop](https://scoop.sh/) My current favorite
- Several more documented [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Package_Manager#History) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_software_package_management_systems#Windows)

---

**Examples of installing MongoDB server with package manager**

You must first install one of the package managers above, then you can use their respective command line interfaces:

**winget:** (currently latest version available is [v4.4.4](https://winget.run/pkg/MongoDB/Server))

```
winget install -e --id MongoDB.Server
```

**scoop:** (currently latest version available is [v5.0](https://github.com/ScoopInstaller/Main/blob/master/bucket/mongodb.json))

```
scoop install mongodb
```

Comment: Yep, I installed it. But the mongod is not starting, I don't understand why..! Screenshot link : https://www.filemail.com/d/huxgtfqneiaifcp

Comment: @ShahariarHossan MongoDB is starting and immediately exiting due to an error. To fix, create the `c:\data\db` directory. Explained in the error message in your screenshot: `"NonExistentPath: Data directory C:\\data\\db\\ not found`